java.IOExpcetion: Operation not permitted
Hello I am dev of server gta san so I was developer launcher on mobile but code it is done and I joined the server (Launcher so joined) and I got error java.IOExpense: Operation not permitted on server gta san. And Android 13+ can join the server, but Android 10+ didn't join the server, and not working also got crashed when I changed to android 10 to android 13+.
so this is my code for build.grade:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        applicationId "King.Supply.Com"
        versionName '1.0.8'
        versionCode 8
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    namespace 'King.Supply.Com'
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
}

Also when I got error java.IOExpcetion: Operation not permitted. So can you help me about fix the error java.IOExpcetion: Operation not permitted for android 10+When I start the code to join the server on my phone Android 12 
and other code:
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.github.hzy3774:AndroidP7zip:v1.7.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.liulishuo.filedownloader:library:1.7.7'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.5.2'
    //implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.3.6'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.agrawalsuneet:DotLoadersPack-Android:v1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:RadioRealButton:v2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:round-corner-progress-bar:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.egslava:edittext-mask:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:colorpickerpreference:2.0.4"
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:Android-Image-Slider:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-core:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:5.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'
    implementation 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Triggertrap:SeekArc:v1.1'
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:colorpickerpreference:2.0.4"
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:2.10.0'
    implementation group: 'org.ini4j', name: 'ini4j', version: '0.5.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "RCRPvn.apk"
    }
    variant.assembleProvider.configure { assemble ->
        assemble.doLast {
            delete "$projectDir\\result\\Studio\\"

            copy {
                from variant.outputs*.outputFile
                into "$projectDir\\..\\result\\Studio\\"
            }

            copy {
                from "$projectDir\\..\\libs\\obj\\local\\armeabi-v7a\\"
                into "$projectDir\\..\\result\\Studio\\"
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}


you have to add all the description and where and what you write in Toast. please share all the code with particular class

I can do more but it is maximum about this
